# Win32_Process enter password without psexec

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, win32-process

I'm running remote command from PowerShell on Windows XP by running this script:

```
$Computer = "ZL45F"
$Command = "cmd.exe /c myapp.exe dosomething"
$Process = ([wmiclass]"\\$Computer\root\cimv2:Win32_Process").create($Command)
```

And it tried to start and execute command. But I need to enter a password when the app starts. How can I do it?

I've tried to do something like

```
$Command = "cmd.exe /c myapp.exe dosomething & password"
```

But password just doesn't entering. It waited for previous step (dosomething).

It shouldn't use psexec or other tools!

Please do not suggest runas. Because it's a password for application, not windows.

Comment: Does the application accept password specified as command-line switch? Some do, like `sqlcmd`. If it doesn't, you need to use an automation tool like AutoIT to send keystrokes to the app.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's just waiting for password typing with the promt "Please enter your password: ".

Comment: Then your best bet is to use 3rd party tools. If that's not possible (why?), maybe VBScript and `SendKeys()` might work.